# Group structure of $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))$for elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve and $\phi: E\to E'$ be an isogeny of degree 2 and $\hat{\phi}$ be its dual isogeny.

How can we calculate the group $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))$?

In the case of $E:y^2=x^3+DX$, page $350$ $9$th line from the bottom of SIlverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves', he reads $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ without explanations.
But group $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))$ looks difficult in general. Do you know any strategy to figure out this group ?
(I also have the same quetion for $E'(\Bbb{Q})/{\phi}(E(\Bbb{Q}))$)

Comment: This is a hard open problem. It depends on the conjectural finiteness of the $2$-primary part of the Tate-Shafarevich group of $E'$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selmer_group#:~:text=The%20Selmer%20group%20of%20an%20isogeny,-The%20Selmer%20group&text=0%20%E2%86%92%20B(K)%2F,A(K))%20is%20finite.

Comment: But page $p360$, $9$th line from the bottom, Silverman reads $E(\Bbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\Bbb{Q}))\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ without explanation. Can we calculate it easily in specific stuation ?

Comment: What edition of the book do you have? Is this taken from Chapter X, "Computing the Mordell-Weil group," section 6, "The Curve $Y^2= X^3+DX$"? In my (1986) edition, this section is found on pages 309-318 (far from your advertised "page 360")

Comment: @Peter a g Sorry, the page was wrong, page 350 is correct. It is in second edition,http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf.